# Notation for Propositional values in Church's "Simple Theory of Types"

Tags: mathematics, notation

In Alanzo Church's "A Formulation of the Simple Theory of Types" (*The Journal of Symbolic Logic* **5** no.2 (1940) 56--68, [`DOI:10.2307/2266170`](https://doi.org/10.2307/2266170)), he adopts the convention that terms of type $\iota$ are nonlogical constants (I presume $\iota$ is chosen because terms of this type are called "individuals"), and terms of type $\omicron$ are for truth values. More explicitly, Church states:

> In the interpretation of the theory it is intended that the subscript shall indicate the type of the variable or constant, $\omicron$ being the type of propositions, $\iota$ the type of individuals, ... (56-57)

So it seems clear that $\iota$ specifically is chosen for "individuals".

I'm at a loss as to why $\omicron$ was chosen, and if there is a mnemonic meaning for it (just as "individual", shortened to "i", then converted to Greek gives us $\iota$).

**Question:** Is there a reason why $\omicron$ was chosen to denote the type of truth values?

Comment: IMO there is no "special" reason; most likely, the choice of [$\iota$ (iota)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota) and [$\omicron$ (omicron)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omicron) is due in analogy with the pair $1$ (*one*) and $0$ (*zero*), reserving the numerals for further use.